# AWS Lambda extension throwing timeout

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to create an extension for nodejs lambda.
It's pretty much the same code as from [example](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/nodejs-example-extension).

**nextRuntime** making **GET** request to
`http://${process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2018-06-01/runtime/invocation/next`

**next** making **GET** request to `http://${process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}/2020-01-01/extension/event/next`

Without **nextRuntime** everything works smoothly but with the **nextRuntime** function call results below.

```js
//Lambda code
export const handler = (event: any) => {
  console.log('LAMBDA LAUNCHED');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda, deployed using AWS CDK!'),
  };
};
```

```js
#EXTENSION CODE
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { next, register } from './extension-api';
import { next as nextRuntime } from './runtime-api';


const EventType = {
  INVOKE: 'INVOKE',
  SHUTDOWN: 'SHUTDOWN',
};

function handleShutdown(event: any) {
  console.log('shutdown', { event });
  process.exit(0);
}

function handleInvoke(event: any) {
  console.log('invoke', event);
}
const timeout = (time: number) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time, 'timeout'));
void (async function main() {
  console.log('extension  started');
  process.on('SIGINT', () => handleShutdown('SIGINT'));
  process.on('SIGTERM', () => handleShutdown('SIGTERM'));
  const extensionId = await register();
  while (true) {
    const event: any = await next(extensionId as string);
    const eventRuntime = await Promise.race([
       nextRuntime(),
       timeout(5000),
    ]);
    console.log('eventRuntime', eventRuntime);
    
    switch (event.eventType) {
      case EventType.SHUTDOWN:
        handleShutdown(event);
        break;
      case EventType.INVOKE:
        handleInvoke(event);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('unknown event: ' + event.eventType);
    }
  }
})();
```

So each time I'm invoking a function, it gives me different results.

First invocation, second, third and seventh.

```
Test Event Name
Test

Response
null

Function Logs
Running custom-extension
extension  started
EXTENSION Name: custom-extension State: Ready Events: [SHUTDOWN,INVOKE]
START RequestId: 589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181 Version: $LATEST
2022-11-18T17:38:52.967Z 589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181 INFO LAMBDA LAUNCHED
event {
eventType: 'INVOKE',
deadlineMs: 1668793137965,
requestId: '589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181',
invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1::function:hello-world',
tracing: {
type: 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
value: 'Root=1-6377c32c-6ee917d7075c9c7655c22500;Parent=61cf916c0c5c3251;Sampled=0'
}
}
eventRuntime timeout
invoke {
eventType: 'INVOKE',
deadlineMs: 1668793137965,
requestId: '589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181',
invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1::function:hello-world',
tracing: {
type: 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
value: 'Root=1-6377c32c-6ee917d7075c9c7655c22500;Parent=61cf916c0c5c3251;Sampled=0'
}
}
event {
eventType: 'SHUTDOWN',
deadlineMs: 1668793139971,
shutdownReason: 'timeout'
}
shutdown {
event: {
eventType: 'SHUTDOWN',
deadlineMs: 1668793139971,
shutdownReason: 'timeout'
}
}
2022-11-18T17:38:57.987Z 589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181 Task timed out after 5.02 seconds

END RequestId: 589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181
REPORT RequestId: 589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181 Duration: 5021.69 ms Billed Duration: 5000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 68 MB Init Duration: 258.09 ms

Request ID
589720df-be2f-482d-a440-f181fe4bd181
```

Fourth invocation, fifth, and six

```
Test Event Name
Test

Response
null

Function Logs
Running custom-extension
extension  started
EXTENSION Name: custom-extension State: Ready Events: [INVOKE,SHUTDOWN]
START RequestId: fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb Version: $LATEST
event {
eventType: 'INVOKE',
deadlineMs: 1668793273802,
requestId: 'fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb',
invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1::function:hello-world',
tracing: {
type: 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
value: 'Root=1-6377c3b4-29e874313e329e1d60d0b457;Parent=42bf3d3b6e9b1f7d;Sampled=0'
}
}
eventRuntime { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
invoke {
eventType: 'INVOKE',
deadlineMs: 1668793273802,
requestId: 'fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb',
invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1::function:hello-world',
tracing: {
type: 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id',
value: 'Root=1-6377c3b4-29e874313e329e1d60d0b457;Parent=42bf3d3b6e9b1f7d;Sampled=0'
}
}
2022-11-18T17:41:09.557Z fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb INFO LAMBDA LAUNCHED
END RequestId: fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb
REPORT RequestId: fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb Duration: 773.61 ms Billed Duration: 774 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 24 MB

Request ID
fc35da60-7019-4f1c-acd7-6575671f3ecb
```

I can't trace the logic in these calls.

Comment: check if it's not going beyond lambda timeout which only works for functions that can run up to 15 minutes.

Comment: @AjayK not it's not going beyond timeout

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling it might be related to cold start. Not sure, though. I'd like to suggest to implement AWS Powertools (as simple and quick) to observe how each exacution behaves: https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-typescript/latest/ Maybe this will give you some answers.